# How do I follow the text of this Longest Common Sequence proof?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np-hard

I'm working through a [proof](https://hal-upec-upem.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00683311/document) that is a simplified version of David Maeirs **LCS** reduction from the **VERTEX**-**COVER** problem and I had a question about a specific set of instructions and how to execute them by hand.

Background Information[image]
This works out to look like the below as a graph (please excuse the grid lines)

[image]

The part I don't understand of the proof

[image]

Now I think this would imply that I need to line up S0-S7 vertically and using that rule show I can find the LCS, which was shown in my proof to be

> $$00000001000000000000000000000100000000000000100000001$$
>   $$0^710^{21}10^{14}10^71$$

I tried doing that but was unable after many attempts to show that I could in fact induce $Topt$ from the sequences below. Could someone explain where I'm going wrong here? Did I misinterpret the instructions?

> $S0 =00000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001$
>
> $S1 =00000000000000100000000000000100000001000000010000000100000001$
>
> $S2 =00000001000000000000001000000000000001000000010000000100000001$
>
> $S3 =00000001000000000000001000000010000000000000010000000100000001$
>
> $S4 =00000001000000010000000000000010000000100000000000000100000001$
>
> $S5 =00000001000000010000000000000010000000100000001000000000000001$
>
> $S6 =00000001000000010000000100000000000000100000000000000100000001$
>
> $S7 =00000001000000010000000100000001000000000000001000000010000000$

EDIT: I tried everything I could think of to see if I could make any of them work but didn't think it was relevant enough to include, if you want to know what I did I can list them.

Comment: This process does not show an algorithm to find a lcs.

Answer (score 1):

The two red-underlined parts of the proof is to **standardize** an LCS solution, that is called $T_{opt}$ therein.

The idea is to push all the $0$'s farthest possible to the right (without passing through its nearest $1$ to the right).

Consider the following two strings:

$s_1=0001000100010001$ (i.e. $n=4$ vertices)

$s_2=0001000\ 00010001000$ (where the space is for visualizing purpose only) (i.e. $u=2$, $v=4$)

A common subsequence (not necessarily longest) can be: $s=0001000 00010001$ (i.e. $u$ is omitted)

The standardization process in the proof is to actually align $s$ against $s_1$, $s_2$.

And, this MUST be standardized to be as follows:

`s1= 0001 0001 0001 0001`

`s2= 0001 000  0001 0001000`

`s = 0001 000  0001 0001`

Similarly, if we omit $v$, then $s=000100010001000$

And, this should be standardized as follows:

`s1= 0001      0001 0001 0001`

`s2= 0001 000  0001 0001 000`

`s = 0001      0001 0001 000`

Finally, we will be able to construct an $n^2+k$-long common subsequence if there exists an independent set of size $n-k$, where for each edge $\{u,v\}$, we omit at least one of them (the ones that are in the independent set) so that it is possible to align like we do above (note that each edge-string $e_j$ contains only $n-1$ symbol $1$'s). And lastly, by complementing a $k$-VC, we have an $(n-k)$-IS.